# Do I need to update distribution certificate and provisioning profile right after generating and installing APNS production certificate?

Tags: iphone, ssl-certificate, appstore-approval

I am working on one app and its uses the Apple push notification. For that there is one apple push services production certificate created by other user/previous developer. I am not able to contact my previous developer for the push certificate p12 along with its private key.

That is why I am trying to generate my own apple push production certificate from the developer site.

But my doubt is if I generate and install that new APNs Production certificate to my keychain , will it affect my existing provision profile and iOS distribution certificate(which is already installed in my keychain)?

Do I have to update them both after installing APNS production certificate ? If yes plz guide me with the procedure.